# Bar Graph (android) disappear when go to negative x axis

Tags: android, graph

I am creating a Bar graph in android using agraphchart library, when I go to negative x Axis and zero point then bar graph just disappear.

Can anyone help my with this?

Comment: Post your code. What have you tried so far. This seems that I can see your monitor's screen by sitting at my place, how can you assume to solve your problem without showing what have you done??

Comment: I solved my problem. Thank's anyway. I know you can't solve my problem without code but I mined someone else has a similar problem and can detect it from my question. :) 
I just add 250 in XYSeries and bar graph drawing far away from 0. Then user can't go to negative xAxis and bar graph does'n disappear. :)

Comment: Glad that you did it man..! Bravo..!